# Issue with Stored Procedures, the delete function runs but no delete is done to the database. Php, mysql, angularjs.

Tags: php, mysql, angularjs, html

I have two tables in my database, 'tbl_player' and 'tbl_teams'.

Im trying to implement a stored procedure where if I delete a team the player should also be deleted. Problem is that everything runs with no errors, and I can see in console that the data is deleted, but no change is made to the database.

(Button at the bottom of the html is calling the php function)

**HTML**

```
<div class="container wrapper">
 <h1 class="text-center">Players in database</h1>
 <br/>
 <div class="">
  <nav class="navbar navbar-dark bg-dark">

   <form >
    <a><button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="add_player()">Add 
      Player <span></span>
    </button></a>
   </form>
   <div>
    <span class="input-group-btn">
     <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search 
         Player">
    </span>
   </div>
  </nav>

  <div class="table-responsive">
   <table class="table table-hover">
    <tr>
     <th>Player ID</th>
     <th>Name</th>
     <th>Email</th>
     <th>Team</th>
    </tr>

    <tr ng-repeat="user in users track by $index">
     <td>{{user.PlayerID}}</td>
     <td>{{user.PlayerName}}</td>
     <td>{{user.PlayerEmail}}</td>
     <td>{{user.TeamName}}</td>
     <td>
       <button class="btn btn-warning" ng- 
          click="update_player(user.PlayerID, user.PlayerName, 
          user.PlayerEmail, user.TeamName)"><span ></span>Edit
       </button>
     </td>

     <td>
      <button class="btn btn-danger" ng-click="delete(user.PlayerID)" 
        title="PlayerDelete"><span></span>Delete
      </button>
     </td>
    </tr>
   </table>
  </div>
 </div>

 <div class="">
  <div class="table-responsive" >
   <table class="table table-hover">
    <tr>
     <th>Team ID</th>
     <th>Team Name</th>
    </tr>
    <tr ng-repeat="teams in teams track by $index">
     <td>{{teams.TeamID}}</td>
     <td>{{teams.TeamName}}</td>  
     <td>
      <button class="btn btn-danger" ng- 
       click="deleteTeam(teams.TeamID)" title="PlayerDelete"><span> 
       </span>Delete
      </button>
     </td>
    </tr>
   </table>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

**teamDelete.php**

```
<?php
include 'DbConfig.php';

$data = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"));

$user = $data->id;

$sql = "CALL deleteTeam ('$user')";

if (mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) {
  echo "Team was deleted";
}
else {
 echo "Err Could not delete Team";
}
mysqli_close($conn);
?>
```

**PlayerController**

```
  $scope.deleteTeam = function(id) {
   console.log(id);
   $http.post("teamDelete.php", {'id':id});
   console.log("Deleted");
   $location.path('/');
   console.log("page loaded again");
  };
```

**MySql**

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `deleteTeam`(IN id 
INT(255))
BEGIN
DECLARE EXIT HANDLER FOR SQLWARNING

BEGIN 
ROLLBACK;
END;

START TRANSACTION;

DELETE FROM tbl_player WHERE PlayerTeam = id;
DELETE FROM tbl_teams WHERE TeamID = id; 

END
```

Comment: i guess you are redirecting it before ajax call is completed try  then to redirect . $http.post("teamDelete.php", {'id':id}).then(function(data){ $location.path('/'); })

Comment: I tried that, still same problem unfortunately.

Comment: Did you give it a call through the rest client. is your api responding the way it should

Comment: you need to make sure that your store procedure and api is working perfactly.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like there is a `COMMIT` statement missing.

If the design is to handle transactions within a stored procedure, it seems like the procedure should finish the transaction, and do the `COMMIT` in the procedure.

As currently written, when the procedure call returns, we're echoing "Team was deleted", but the work in the database hasn't actually been completed.

The caller only knows that the procedure returned. It doesn't know if a warning was encountered, which caused the `ROLLBACK` statement to be issued.